# Сформировать масcив и поместить него все неповторяющиеся числа

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Дан массив целых чисел X=(x1,x2,...,xn). Сформировать массив Y=(y1,y2,...,ym), поместив в него в порядке убывания все различные (неповторяющиеся) числа, входящие в массив X.

Пытался вот так, но не корректно работает:

```
void transferElements ()
{
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        f = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (X[i] == X[j])
            {
                f = 0;              
                break;
            }
            if (f == 1)
            Y[i] = X[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Стандартную библиотеку использовать можно? Тогда копируем, сортируем, вызываем unique и erase... Если нельзя - все то же, но своими руками :)

Answer (score 1):

Huricane, в отличии от примера Timur Yalimov попробую решить задачу вообще без внешних функций (типа qsort):

Основная логика в следующем:

Мы просматриваем все элементы и ищем каждый раз максимальное, но меньше максимального на прошлом этапе поиска максимального

Таким образом - каждый этап мы будем находить одно уникальное число в порядке убывания

```
int transferElements(int* x, int x_size, int* y)
{
    int y_size = 0;

    int x_max = INT_MAX; // максимально возможное число int ~ +2.000.000.000

    for (int i = 0; i < x_size; i ++)
    {
        // определить максимальное число в массиве x, не превышающее x_max
        int x_local_max = INT_MIN; // минимально возможное число int ~ -2.000.000.000

        for (int j = 0; j < x_size; ++j)
        {
            if ((x[j] > x_local_max) && (x[j] < x_max))
                x_local_max = x[j];
        }

        // записать найденное число в выходной массив
        if (x_local_max > INT_MIN)
            y[y_size++] = x_local_max;

        // снизить границу максимальных чисел
        x_max = x_local_max;
    }

    return y_size;
}
```

Недостаток - алгоритм не оптимален и в массиве не должно быть числа MAX_INT (мы его изначально как критерий используем)

От второго недостатка ты можешь избавиться уже сам

**P.S.**

а твой алгоритм не работает ну потому что он и не должен работать - например у тебя только проверка на равно есть (а значит больше-меньше ты не определяешь) и запись только в Y (а значит никак не воздействушь на X)

**P.P.S.**

чуть-чуть оптимальнее сделал - когда не находятся новые числа, не надо делать дальнейшие проверки - можно прервать цикл

```
int transferElements(int* x, int x_size, int* y)
{
    int y_size = 0;

    int x_max = INT_MAX; // максимально возможное число int ~ +2.000.000.000

    for (int i = 0; i < x_size; i ++)
    {
        // определить максимальное число в массиве x, не превышающее x_max
        int x_local_max = INT_MIN; // минимально возможное число int ~ -2.000.000.000

        for (int j = 0; j < x_size; ++j)
        {
            if ((x[j] > x_local_max) && (x[j] < x_max))
                x_local_max = x[j];
        }

        // завершить обработку, если новых чисел не найдено
        if (x_local_max <= INT_MIN)
            break;

        // записать найденное число в выходной массив
        y[y_size++] = x_local_max;

        // снизить границу максимальных чисел
        x_max = x_local_max;
    }

    return y_size;
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример не работает, если в массиве `x` присутствуют повторяющиеся элементы. [Пруф](https://ideone.com/vcRP5v)

Comment: @wololo, теперь работет
https://ideone.com/h5XQIZ

Надо было просто 1 проверку при записи в массив y поставить, чтоб записывались данные, только когда они найдены были

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define SIZE (7)

int compare(const void * x1, const void * x2)   

{
   return ( *(int*)x2 - *(int*)x1 );            
}

int Task(int * arr, int * res)

{
    qsort(arr, SIZE, sizeof(int), compare);

    int res_cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

    {
       if ((arr[i] != arr[i + 1] && arr[i] != arr[i] - 1 && i != 0) || (i == 0)) 

        {
           res[res_cnt++] = arr[i];
        }  
    }

    return res_cnt;
}


int main()

{

    int array[SIZE]  = { 1, 0, 50, 50, 20, 20, 300 };
    int result[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int result_size = Task(array, result);
}
```

Здесь в result_size будет храниться размер получившегося массива, если вам разрешено - можете по нему выделять динамическую память.

Comment: `*(int*)x2 - *(int*)x1` а если разность не поместится в тип `int`?

Answer (score 0):

[Способ №1](https://ideone.com/mmM5AQ) (доводим ваш пример кода до рабочего состояния):

```
using value_type = int;

int CompFunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    if ( *static_cast<const value_type *>(a) > *static_cast<const value_type *>(b) )
        return -1;
    else
        if ( *static_cast<const value_type *>(a) < *static_cast<const value_type *>(b))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}

size_t TransferElement(value_type *x, size_t size, value_type *y)
{
    if ( size == 0 )
        return 0;

    size_t ySize = 0;
    bool flag;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i )
    {
        flag = true;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j != ySize; ++j )
            if ( x[i] == y[j] )
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        if ( flag )
        {
            y[ySize] = x[i];
            ++ySize;
        }
    }
    qsort(y, ySize, sizeof(value_type), CompFunc);
    return ySize;
}
```

---

[Способ №2](https://ideone.com/egEJEW) (Немного оптимизируем ваш алгоритм):

```
size_t TransferElements(value_type *x, size_t size, value_type *y)
{
    if ( size == 0 )
        return 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i )
        y[i] = x[i];
    qsort(y, size, sizeof(value_type), CompFunc);

    value_type controlVal = y[0];
    size_t ySize = 1;

    for ( i = 1; i != size; ++i )
        if ( controlVal != y[i] )
        {
            controlVal = y[i];
            y[ySize] = controlVal;
            ++ySize;
        }
    return ySize;
}
```

Сложность первого способа `O(N^2)`, сложность второго `O(N)` (без учёта сортировки). Однако второй способ требует, чтобы размер массива `y` был таким же как и `x`.

---

[Способ №3](https://ideone.com/zceAWt) (по мотивам комментария @Harry):

```
typedef vector<int> vect_type;
vect_type x, y;
//...
y = x;
sort(y.begin(), y.end(), greater<vect_type::value_type>());
auto last = unique(y.begin(), y.end());
y.erase(last, y.end());
```